# Increment in array wrong value

Tags: php, loops

I searched this site before and i don't find an answer.

I have this code:

```
for($i=0;$i<=8;$i++){
$statistic = $array['title']['content']['$i']['value'];
................
}
```

And the script return one valor =128, but isn't corect... What's wrong in this code? Thank you !

Comment: We'd need to see your $array to help. Might want to change `['$i']` to `[$i]`

Comment: I don't know how look `$array` but probably: `$statistic = $array['title']['content'][$i]['value'];`

Comment: Is this a real question? C'mon, we don't know anything about your array an neither about your return value. Try to add some details and I bet the answer will come to you

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the quotes from around the $i: `$statistic = $array['title']['content'][$i]['value'];`